# UITableView drag blocks all other animations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, uiscrollview

I have an App that streams video using an `AVPlayer`. I also have a progress bar and a `tableView` on the same view.

The problem I'm having is that as soon as I drag the `tableView` while the video is playing, both the player and the progress bar's animations/playback freeze. As soon as the scroll animation is done playback and the progress bar animations resume normally.

Also, if I animate the `tableView` using `[selectRowAtIndexPath animated]`, then playback is not affected at all.

Is there something in the `tableView`/`scrollView` code that blocks these kinds of animations?

Answer (score 0):

You can try separate the player and the other UI logic in different views. I don't think it will help but you can try :)

Comment: Unfortunately no this wont work. I have other tableviews (for filtering etc) on different views and even when those are dragged the player freezes

Comment: It should be something about the `NSRunLoop` modes of the `UITableView`. I've had similar problem with `NSTimer` and `UIScrollView` scrolling.